# 3x3 Linear ODE System with Three Repeated Eigenvalues Equal to 0

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When solving the problem below:

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3l305.png)

I find that there is one eigenvalue equal to 0 and an eigenvector equal to [1; 0; 1]. How do you go about solving this system so the solution isn't just constants?

Comment: I understand the meaning of algebraic and geometric multiplicity but a little confused about generalized eigenvectors

Comment: Hmmm the generalized eigenvectors now make sense but I'm getting a different answer than you. I get: x(t)=c1*(1/2)*(t^2), y(t)=(c2*t)+c3, and z(t) = (c1*(1/2)*(t^2)) + (c2*t) + (2*c3)

Comment: Since one eigenvector is 0, then it has multiplicity three. The first eigenvector is v1=[1;0;1], the next generalized is v2=[0;1;1], and the third is v3=[0;1;2]. Then the general solution would be x(t) = (c1*(0.5*(t^2)))*v1 + c2*t*v2 + c3*v3. Or x(t)=c1*(1/2)*(t^2), y(t)=(c2*t)+c3, and z(t) = (c1*(1/2)*(t^2)) + (c2*t) + (2*c3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is of course 
$$
    X(t) = \exp(t A) X(0)
$$
and as $A^3=0$ this series reduces to simply 
$$
    X(t) = (I + tA + \tfrac12t^2A^2)  X(0)
$$

Comment: That's a good point, if we already have nilpotent we do not need Jordan form; I came across something similar I had not known: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2722246/finding-nilpotent-and-diagonalizable-operators-for-a-linear-transformation-t/2722317#2722317