How can I raise this matrix to a variable power?
I want to evaluate this:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}^n
$$
How would I approach this?
This isn't a homework problem. I was just thinking about a linear algebra approach to the problem of summing all numbers from $n$ to $1$ and found that
$$
M^n\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
n\\\
1
\end{bmatrix}_0
= \sum_{i = 1}^n i
$$
(where $M$ is the matrix above and $_0$ is the first element of the product vector). Is it possible to calculate the matrix exponentiation without already knowing how to calculate the sum?

Your matrix is $M=I + N,$   where the $N$  is nilpotent and commutes with $I.$  Find $N^2$ and $N^3$  Then find $M^n$  by the binomial formula

$$ N = \left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 1 & 0 \
0 & 0 & -1 \
0 & 0 & 0 \
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$ N^2 = \left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 0 & -1 \
0 & 0 & 0 \
0 & 0 & 0 \
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$ N^3 = \left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 0 & 0 \
0 & 0 & 0 \
0 & 0 & 0 \
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Thanks, very interesting! How did you recognize the decomposition into $I$ and nilpotent $N$ so quickly? What do you mean by commutes, under addition or multiplication? Isn't addition always commutative, and multiplication by $I$ also commutative? I'm still struggling with applying the binomial formula part...

@GavinWahl : welcome to MSE ... I am curious where question originated from

Well, for a diagonal matrix $D$  finding $D^n$  is easy. So, given diagonalizable $W$  with $P^{-1} W P = D,$  you get $P^{-1} W^n P = D^n,$  so that $W^n = P D^n P^{-1}.$  Generally one is guaranteed a Jordan form, some  $P^{-1} W P = J,$   with $J$  in Jordan Normal Form. Your matrix is already in Jordan-Chevalley form

I commutes means that the binomial theorem can be applied because terms like $IN$ and $NI$ are not differentiated. $M^n = (I + N)^n = \sum_{s=0}^\infty \binom{n}{s}I^{n-s}N^s= \binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{1}N + \binom{n}{2}N^2...$ and the rest should follow.

Found some posts on Jordan-Chevalley  that explain the terms used. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2423596/jordan-chevalley-vs-jordan-normal-decomposition     ....... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form   ......  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%E2%80%93Chevalley_decomposition

Here's a general theory for applying functions to square matrices. Any square matrix $M$ has a Jordan normal form: a decomposition $M = SJS^{-1}$ where $S$ is invertible and $J$ is block-diagonal $J = J_1 \oplus J_2 \oplus \cdots\,$ with the Jordan blocks $J_i$ of the form
$$J_i = \begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_i & 1\\
& \lambda_i & \ddots\\
&& \ddots & 1\\
&&& \lambda_i
\end{bmatrix}$$
for some block size and some scalar $\lambda_i$. Then to apply a (sufficiently well-behaved) function to the matrix, we have $f(M) = S \, f(J) \, S^{-1}$.
In your scenario, we have the function $f : x \mapsto x^n$. To compute the Jordan normal form of $M$, it's already very close to the desired form so we can just determine it by inspection:
$$M = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix} = SJS^{-1}.$$
Then from the result in the page above, we get
$$f(J) = f\left(\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}
f(1) & f'(1) & \frac{f''(1)}{2!}\\
0 & f(1) & f'(1)\\
0 & 0 & f(1)
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & n & \frac{n(n-1)}{2}\\
0 & 1 & n\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Taking the similarity transformation back, we find that
$$M^n = S f(J) S^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & n & -\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\\
0 & 1 & -n\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.$$
As an aside, when the matrix is diagonalizable (which yours is not), the formula simplifies because we can take $M = S D S^{-1}$ where $D = \mathrm{diag}(d_1, d_2, \ldots)$ is diagonal, hence applying $f$ to $D$ is simply $f(D) = \mathrm{diag}(f(d_1), f(d_2), \ldots)$ (i.e., we don't need to compute off-diagonal elements and take derivatives).

Great answer! Thanks
